# SQL Query improvement question conceptual

Tags: sql, database, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

Working on improvement of query where I have a inner join on two core tables with large data and then using where clause to filter out some data.

I was thinking of filtering first with indexing on those filters and then use inner join. Will it run faster ?

For example:

- Table1 - TableX
- Columns - Id, ColX1, ColX2, ColX3
- Table2 - TableY
- Columns - YId, ColY1, ColY2, ColY3

Current query

```
SELECT 
    K.Id, K.ColX1, K.ColX2, K.ColX3, G.YId 
FROM 
    TableX K 
INNER JOIN 
    TableY G ON K.Id = G.YId  
WHERE
    (K.ColX1 IN '0') 
    AND (G.YId = '1234') 
    AND (K.ColX2 = '4567')
```

New query

```
(SELECT Id, ColX1, ColX2, ColX3 
 FROM TableX 
 WHERE Id = '1234' AND ColX2 = '4567' AND ColX1 IN '0') K
INNER JOIN
    (SELECT YId FROM TableY WJERE YId = '1234') G ON K.Id = G.YId
```

Comment: You have to read about the phases of processing the query:1- Parsing. 2- Compilation. 3- Execution.

Comment: SQL isn't an imperative language. It doesn't execute what you write in the order you write it. It's a declarative language; you use SQL to express a problem statement, and the engine determines what *it* sees as the optimal plan to solve it. In all likelihood both your suggestions will yield the exact same execution plan.

Comment: that rewrite won't gain you anything. Oracle is already applying the predicates to each table as it reads them. If you actually provided more realistic predicate values it would tell us more (low vs. high cardinality predicates), plus an execution plan.

Comment: You need to check the execution plan and see that these are the same queries

Answer (score 2):

The thing is, any database worth its salt is going to perform an optimization step called "Predicate Pushdown". What that means is that if it sees a predicate (condition) in the WHERE clause where tables are joined, it will push those predicates down to the selection of data against those tables, where appropriate. So your rewrite may not make a difference as it will merely describe what the system is likely already executing behind the scenes.

That being said, your current rewrite is incorrect. Subqueries for both tables should be contained entirely within the FROM clause.

```
SELECT K.Id, K.ColX1, K.ColX2, K.ColX3, G.YId 
FROM (SELECT * FROM TableX WHERE ColX1 = '0' AND ColX2 = '4567' AND ID = '1234') K 
    INNER JOIN (SELECT * FROM TableY WHERE G.YId = '1234') G 
        ON K.Id = G.YId
```

You can run an `EXPLAIN` on both versions and see if there is a difference. Likely there won't be, and, in the end, you have a much more difficult SQL to maintain as your `id` filter exists in two places.